# wp_email template unable to change

Tags: php, wordpress, email, templates

I have created a basic html template to use in a wp_email() function.
Here is the the template code:

```
<?php

$opties = json_decode($array_opties);


$message .= '
<p>'. date("Y-m-d H:i:s") .'</p>
<p>'. $titel .'</p>
<p>'. $uitvoering_field .'</p>
<p>'. $vermogen_gewicht_gewicht .'</p>
<p>'. $vermogen_gewicht_type .'</p>
<p>'. $vermogen_gewicht_kw .'</p>
<p>'. $vermogen_gewicht_prijs .'</p>
<p><img src="'. $kleurafbeelding .'" /></p>
<p>'. $kleurtitel .'</p>
<p>'. $kleurprijs .'</p>
<p><img src="'. $bekledingafbeelding .'" /></p>
<p>'. $bekledingtitel .'</p>
<p>'. $bekledingprijs .'</p>
<p><img src="'. $velgenafbeelding .'" /></p>
<p>'. $velgentitel .'</p>
<p>'. $velgenprijs .'</p>
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
        <thead>
                <tr>
                        <th>Optiepakket</th>
                        <th>Omschrijving</th>
                        <th>Prijs</th>
                </tr>
        </thead>
';
foreach ($opties as &$optie) {
$message .= '
        <tr>
            <td>'. $optie->titel .'</td>
            <td width="250">'. $optie->omschrijving .'</td>
            <td>'. $optie->prijs .'</td>
        </tr>
        ';
}



$message .= '
</table>
<p>'. $bedrijf .'</p>
<p>'. $naam .'</p>
<p>'. $adres .'</p>
<p>'. $postcode .'</p>
<p>'. $plaats .'</p>
<p>'. $telefoon .'</p>
<p>'. $mobiel .'</p>

';
```

This is the code I use to send the email:

```
                $located = locate_template('mail.php');
            if(!empty($located)){
                    include $located;
            } else {
                    include (ABSPATH. 'wp-content/plugins/quido/frontend/mail.php');
            }
    $email_ontvangers = array('example@email.com', 'example@email.com');
    $headers = 'From: from <email@example.com>' . "\r\n";
    wp_mail( $email_ontvangers, 'text', $message, $headers );
```

This was all working correctly, But I needed to add some strings to the email so I added them to the row with `<p></p>` elements. But this did not change the email. Then I added a table head to the table. As you can see there are 3 th tags I added one and this did not change the email. Then I just deleted everything in the file and that did not change the email. So I am sort of lost. I also tried to change the path the wp_mail used my template. So I changed 'mail.php' to the full path of the template which did also not have success. So how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue. It is due to the header not containing this line of code:

```
$headers = 'From: From <example@email.com>' . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"" ."\r\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

> The default content type is 'text/plain' which does not allow using
>   HTML. You can set the content type of the email either by using the
>   'wp_mail_content_type' filter or by including a header like
>   "Content-type: text/html". Be careful to reset 'wp_mail_content_type'
>   back to 'text/plain' after you send your message, though, because
>   failing to do so could lead to unexpected problems with e-mails from
>   WP or plugins/themes.

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_content_type' );
function set_content_type( $content_type ) {
    return 'text/html';
}
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_mail_content_type

Comment: I have a function.php in my plugin folder (where all the mail is going on) and one from my wordpress template. In the wordpress template function.php this code was added:                                               add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', function($content_type){
 return 'text/html';
});  I don't know if i should add it to the plug in function file too ? Also this would probably not change the email because my email normally sends even if i delete all the code in the template as stated above, So would this work ? I'll try to add it my plugin now.

Comment: I tested this and it is not working, The set_content_type i used does the same thing.